# storing state in a c++ dll

Tags: c++, dll

Im having issues on how to store state in a dll in c++. What i currently have is something like this:

```
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
  #define DECLSPEC __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define DECLSPEC __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace FOO
{
    extern "C"
    {
        DECLSPEC bool initialize();                    
        DECLSPEC void addSomething();
        DECLSPEC void removeSomething();
        DECLSPEC void shutDown();  
    }
}

#endif // FOO
```

Now i want my dll to be able have some sort of state. For example i want the stuff that get's added by addSomething() to be stored in a std::vector inside the dll and be able to acess that same vector from removeSomething(). Since my dll just exports a set of functions, i don't really see a clean way to do that. The only ting that currently comes to my mind are global variables inside the dll. Is there a better solution than that? I kind of want to avoid using global variables even if they are only inside the dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose to either use global variables to store the data or you can pass back a handle to the caller (from `initialize()` for example) and hang your data off that.  The caller then passes back this handle when calling any of the exposed methods; for example:

```
typedef void *MyHandle;

// NULL would be an error
DECLSPEC MyHandle initialize();
DECLSPEC void addSomething(MyHandle handle);
DECLSPEC void destroy(MyHandle handle);
```

In the implementation you cast `MyHandle` to a concrete type which is not exposed to the caller.

This allows your DLL to be used more than once within the process and allows you to avoid the use of global variables.

I find your use of both `namespace` and `extern "C"` strange; I think you should stick to C-Linkage to make your DLL useful from more languages.

Comment: Isn't wrapping your exported functions in a namespace a good idea to avoid name conflicts by the program loading the dll? Especially something very unspecific like a function called "bool initialize();" Might already exist in the program loading the dll. Are there any other downsides except this making the dll not usable by other languages and should i change to extern "C++" if i keep the namespace?

Comment: @Eric Yeah you should choose C or C++ linkage; as it stands it can only be used in C++ and won't support function overloading as you have turned off name-mangling by using `extern "C"`.  If you are worried about names in C, you should use a more domain-specific prefix or something.